# Using ngrx in ionic guard

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic3, ngrx

In ionic I have guard. In my old version it looked like this (I'm getting data from server):

```
ionViewCanEnter(): Promise<any> {
    return this.miejscaService.pobierzSzczegoly(this.navParams.data)
         .do(resp => {
            this.atrakcja = resp;
        })
        .toPromise();
}
```

It worked perfectly but I want to cache data so I'm using now `ngrx` store.
I get data but guard is not working:/ No error. Have no idea why...

```
ionViewCanEnter(): Promise<any> {
    return this.store.select(getWybranaAtrakcja)
        .do(resp => {
            console.log('I\'m here');
            console.log(resp);
            this.atrakcja = resp;
        })
        .toPromise();
}
```

Comment: you are calling service in viewCanEnter; You have to dispatch an action to get  and store to store

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I googled there is small `bug` (in my opinion). Reaching to store was never resolved (in terms of promise).
https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/issues/1088

```
ionViewCanEnter(): Promise<boolean> {
    let resolver = (subsription: Subscription, resolve: Function, result: any) => {
        resolve(result);
        subsription.unsubscribe();
    };
    let rejecter = (subsription: Subscription, reject: Function, error: any) => {
        reject(error);
        subsription.unsubscribe();
    };

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        let subscription = this.store.select(getWybranaAtrakcja)
            .pipe(
                filter(resp => !!(resp))
            )
            .subscribe(
                result => {
                    this.atrakcja = result;
                    resolver(subscription, resolve, result);
                },
                error => {
                    rejecter(subscription, reject, error);
                }
            );
    });
}
```